# Is "walk on" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, verbs

Are these 2 the same?

1. > Do you want to walk on Waterfront?
2. > Do you want to take a walk on Waterfront?

I know 2 is more common, but just curious if I use 1, how that would sound?

Comment: Can you clarify why *Waterfront* is capitalized? Is it the name of something— a boardwalk, a street, a park— or is it a particular waterfront in a particular district or city?

Comment: Waterfront is a public cross walk along Potomac river in Washington D.C, hence the capital W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, depending on context.

2 Implies that you're not yet taking a walk, and suggesting walking on Waterfront as an activity.

1 Implies that you're already out walking, either for leisure or to go somewhere, and you are asking what route you want to take.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but with 'walk on' the "walk" is a verb,

In the second one, using 'a walk', walk is a noun.

They mean the same thing accept that one is a verb and the other is a noun. But they are still the same word.

[This link has both definitions on it.](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=walk%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

It's pretty simple though, the first one:

> Would you like *to* **walk** (which is an action a.k.a. a verb) on the Waterfront?

The second one:

> Would you like to take *a* **walk** (the "*a*" causes '**walk**' to be *a* thing a.k.a. a noun) on the Waterfront?

Comment: In my (British) English, 2) is less natural than 1), but a more natural form is _Would you like to go for a walk on the waterfront?_

Answer (score 0):

> Do you want to take a walk on **the** Waterfront?

is to walk alongside the water

> Do you want to talk on **the** Waterfront?

only means you are conversing while next to the water, you may be sitting, you may be walking.
It is ambiguous what additional actions you both are doing.

Comment: My original question was Walk on the Watefront, not Talk on the Waterfront. Is Walk incorrect?

Comment: @Arash: You do realise that ***walk*** and ***talk*** are two completely different words that have *nothing in common* apart from the fact that they both contain three of the same letters?

Comment: Someone edited the question to and changed Walk to Talk!! My main question has Walk in both sentences.

Comment: oic. I hadn't realised that (consequently I closevoted as "Unclear", but I've now cancelled that).